# How can I output my javascript code to HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eval

I am finishing up on writing a javascript component and I want to provide a bunch of examples to illustrate the config properties, events, methods and such...

I currently have the following HTML to document a single property:

```
      <div class="conf">
        <div class="opt-name">allowFreeEntries</div>
        <code>boolean</code>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="opt-desc">Restricts or allows the user to validate typed entries.<br/>Defaults to <em>true</em>
            <a class="opt-ex">View an example</a>
            <span class="hidden">{"allowFreeEntries": false}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When clicking the "View an example" link, I pop open another div containing my component with its default config mixed in with the custom config given in the hidden span:

```
$('.conf .opt-ex').click(function(){
    var raw = $(this).next().html();
    var rawCfg = JSON.parse(raw);
    var exId = 'example-' + $('div[id^="example-"]').length + 1;
    var cfg = $.extend({
        renderTo: $('#' + exId),
        width: 590
    }, rawCfg);
    $('<div/>',{id: exId}).insertBefore(this);
    new MyComponent(cfg);
});
```

This all works out pretty well... Here comes the tricky part. I would like to output the full evaluated code as raw HTML right above the component. What I want to display to the user is this:

```
        <code><pre>
        new MagicSuggest({
            renderTo: $('#example-1'),
            width: 590,
            allowFreeEntries: false                    
        });
        </pre></code>
```

I've done a few experiments but they all seemed clumsy. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It doesn't look clumsy to me ... do you have a specific question?

Comment: the question is how can I output the last code part from the first two?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to print an object's value within new MagicSuggest string. AFAIK you just have to use string append for appending this.
For printing the object itself you can use

```
   var printObj = typeof JSON != "undefined" ? JSON.stringify : function(obj) {
     var arr = [];
     $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
     var next = key + ": ";
     next += $.isPlainObject(val) ? printObj(val) : val;
     arr.push( next );
     });
     return "{ " +  arr.join(", ") + " }";
   };
```

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: JSON.stringify would work if all values were constants and not function calls like $('#example-1')